# jQuery to disable radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where I would like to disable one radio button. I successfully did it with Chrome Devops Console, but somehow when trying to add the code to the site I can't get it to work. Input won't become disabled. I've cleared sites cache etc, so it should not be a problem with that and I can see that the code is on the site when checking the source code.

Page: https://shop-rain.com/product/wild-jumpsuit/

I've already tried to the code to header and footer (between head-tags and after content). I've also tried adding the code internally and externally (to external file). None of these things make a difference.

jQuery is loaded on the site and every other javascript/jQuery code works.

```
/* I've tried this */
$( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' ).prop( "disabled", true );

/* And this */
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' ).prop( "disabled", true );
});
```

I would like to make the 'XS'-size button disabled since it's sold out but the current system does not allow to display disabled options.

---

Tried to solve the problem with linked "duplicate question", but there is no luck. Tried these:

```
function disableInput() {
    jQuery("input[id=tmcp_choice_1_0_4]:radio").attr('disabled',true);
}

disableInput();
```

```
$($( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' )[0]).prop( "disabled", true );
```

```
setTimeout(function(){ $( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' ).prop( "disabled", true ); }, 5000);
```

None of these work :/

Comment: `$($( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' )[0]).prop( "disabled", true );` Need to target the index since the jQuery selector returns an array of elements.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your Sources panel to see if that code is being run?

Comment: Not true, Josh. See the duplicate answer.

Comment: Visiting your website that area looks like it's running asynchronous - maybe from an ajax call - could it be that the element is not loaded before you try to disable it?

Comment: Just for debug purposes, can you try to see if this works? setTimeout(function(){ $( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' ).prop( "disabled", true ); }, 5000);

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge I tried your script, did not work :/ Should I look for some kind of error through consol etc when using that?

Comment: @isherwood not sure how to do that, so no I haven't. Looking into it now!

Comment: @isherwood I used breakpoint and when reaching the javascript I'm trying to implement the site is not fully loaded yet, inputs are not showing etc. So I guess the script doesn't work because it is loaded before the inputs are loaded? It doesn't matter if I change the script to header or to footer, still loads before rest of the site :/

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready (or you need to run your script in a callback on whatever function might be getting in the way--we can't tell from what you've shown). Also, this post is closed. If you'd like more help, post a new question with the correct information.

Comment: @isherwood Tried `$(function() {
 $( '#tmcp_choice_1_0_4' ).prop( "disabled", true );
});` , no luck. Now the page loads before the code above is run, but it still doesn't work. I stated in the first message that I've already tried this way. Not sure why this is closed?

Comment: Because the issue isn't with your jQuery, apparently. We know that the method you're using works. The issue is with your implementation of it, into which we have little insight, and about which you didn't ask above. Please post a new question asking about your scenario, not about disabling radio buttons. Over and out.